# Можно ли взаимодействовать с exe из C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, exe, executable

Добрый вечер, подскажите пожалуйста как взаимодействовать с exe-файлом из C++ кода? Меня интересует вариант эмуляции обращения через командную строку.

Я пытался сделать что то вроде:

```
system("cmd TestCSharp.exe");
```

Но это всего лишь запустило командную строку.

Comment: `system("TestCSharp.exe arg1 arg2 arg3");` - это, что ли?

Comment: @PinkTux нет, подмена `stdin` и `stdout` (и `stderr`?).

Comment: @Кнопкатык, какая-то непонятная формулировка "вариант эмуляции обращения через командную строку" :-)

Comment: @PinkTux правильно меня поняли. Не туда запихнул exe, теперь все работает, спасибо!

Comment: А, то есть, всё-таки не эмуляция? Окей.

Comment: Например, `system("cmd /c TestCSharp.exe");` :)